# Remove Metabox from Menus screen

Tags: menus, admin, metabox

Been digging into WP files for a bit and think I just might be missing something. The end-goal is to remove the `Theme Locations` metabox from the Menus screen if someone doesn't have a certain capability `manage_options`. I know, a little odd for usability, but there's only one menu and we're trying to make this harder to screw up ;)

Looking at `/wp-admin/nav-menu.php` around line `383` I see `wp_nav_menu_setup()` so I tried to add the following as a filter, but with no luck so far:

```
function roots_remove_nav_menu_metaboxes() {
// Remove Theme Locations from users without the 'manage_options' capability
    if (current_user_can('manage_options') == false) {
        remove_meta_box('wp_nav_menu_locations_meta_box', 'nav-menus', 'side');     // theme locations
    }
}
add_action('wp_nav_menu_setup', 'roots_remove_nav_menu_metaboxes',9999);
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The box gets added in wp_nav_menu_setup(), so you'll have to remove it sometime after that and before it's being output later in nav-menus.php. There don't seem to be any action hooks you can use there, but admin-header.php has a few. You could try this:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-nav-menus.php', 'roots_remove_nav_menu_metaboxes' );
```

I've never tried removing metaboxes from the menu screen, though, and it's untested, so no idea if it works.

Comment: +1 This works as well. The admin header is included after the meta-boxes are set up with `p_nav_menu_setup()`

Comment: Very cool! Thanks everyone for their help with this one!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's a hook. In fact there doesn't seem to be an appropriate one at all. But inside `wp_nav_menu_setup()`, the `manage_nav-menus_columns` is called shortly after the metaboxes are added. You can hook into that and remove it:

```
add_action( 'manage_nav-menus_columns', 'my_remove_meta_locations_box' );
function my_remove_meta_locations_box($columns) {
     if ( ! current_user_can('manage_options') )          
          remove_meta_box('nav-menu-theme-locations', 'nav-menus', 'side');

    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: By added, I don't mean added to the page, but when `add_meta_box` is called.

Answer (score 2):

A fast an easy option is to use the plugin [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/), this support this as option for different roles.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the metabox, you could hide it with CSS, e.g.:

```
#nav-menu-theme-locations {
    display: none;
}
```

Your issue with removing the box itself is most likely an issue with ordering, either trying to remove the box before it has been added, or removing it after it has already been sent to the user

Comment: Hey @Tom - I know I'm being a stickler, but would rather find a function to do this -- I figured the `9999` priority would take care of the ordering (making sure it's called last). I'm sure it's just "how" I'm calling it...

Comment: No I meant the ordering of actions, e.g. the wp_nav_menu_setup action you're hooking into may be called too late or early in the process.

Comment: Bah - my bad. K I'll keep digging to see if I can find out.